# Dynamically disable hbm2ddl.auto?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a eclipse workspace with many projects, one project "shareddata" contains all my jpa entities, services, persistence.xml (using spring-data) and such. In my other projects i have included "shareddata" as dependency in my maven pom.xml .

When i start one of the other projects, jpa/hibernate validates and updates my database tables (hbm2ddl.auto = true). This works nicely.

But to test my entire project in need to start several projects that all include the "shareddata" project. So every single project validates and updates my database tables. This takes quite a bit of time.

Is it possible only to enable "hbm2ddl.auto" for one single project? Or is it possible to dynamically disable "hbm2ddl.auto" at application startup?

If that is possible than i could start up my jms server project and do database validation. Next i start up my other projects (tomcat and several server apps) and they won't do the database validation.

Saves me a lot of time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did such things via system properties. Unfortunately I do not know how do you initialize hibernate context. I personally did it via Spring that supports system properties using `${propName}` syntax. If you can use this notation just use it in your configuration files and set appropriate property in the beginning of your unit test.

Comment: Cheers, your reply made me look where jpa was initialized, i use the same xml everywhere and never bothered to look what it actually did, cause it always worked. In the end i found out that LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean did the initialization. I'll post a answer with the details.

Answer (score 1):

It took a little while to figure out, but jpa is configured in my applicationContext.xml (or variations like root-context.xml). LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does the initialization.

Lucky LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean accepts parameters that seem to override the values set in persistence.xml . So i set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to none in persistence.xml and use the following xml to enable hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto for a specific project:

```
<!-- Add JPA support -->
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this may help someone with the same problem.